# how to create contact detail page using controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, controller-extension

```
public with sharing class ContactDetailController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
    public string conId{get;set;}

    public ContactDetailController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) 
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
        // Fields being cloned
       conId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        //this.standardController.addFields(new List<String> {'FirstName','lastname','mobilephone','Accountid','otherphone','title','fax','Department','Email','Birthdate','AssistantName','Reportstoid','Assistantphone','leadsource','OtherStreet','MailingCity','othercity','MailingState','otherstate', });

        // getDescribe that retrive whole fields of the particular object
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe();
        List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();
        for(string apiName : r.fields.getMap().keySet()){
            apiNames.add(apiName);
        }
        System.debug(apiNames);
        this.standardController.addFields(apiNames);

    }
    public PageReference cloneButton()
    {
        // Record being cloned
        Contact con = (Contact) standardController.getRecord(); 
        // Custom clone logic
        Contact clonedcon = new Contact();
        clonedcon.FirstName = con.FirstName;
        clonedcon.lastName = con.lastName; 
        clonedcon.mobilephone = con.mobilephone;
        clonedcon.Accountid = con.Accountid;
        clonedcon.otherphone = con.otherphone;
        clonedcon.title = con.title;
        clonedcon.fax = con.fax;
        clonedcon.Department = con.Department;
        clonedcon.Email = con.Email;
        clonedcon.Birthdate = con.Birthdate;
        clonedcon.AssistantName = con.AssistantName; 
        clonedcon.Reportstoid = con.Reportstoid;
        clonedcon.Assistantphone = con.Assistantphone;
        clonedcon.leadsource = con.leadsource;
        clonedcon.OtherStreet= con.OtherStreet;
        clonedcon.MailingCity = con.MailingCity;
        clonedcon.othercity = con.othercity;
        clonedcon.MailingState = con.MailingState;
        clonedcon.otherstate = con.otherstate;
        clonedcon.MailingPostalCode = con.MailingPostalCode;
        clonedcon.otherpostalcode = con.otherpostalcode;
        clonedcon.MailingCountry = con.MailingCountry; 
        clonedcon.othercountry = con.othercountry;
        clonedcon.Languages__c = con.Languages__c;
        clonedcon.Level__c = con.Level__c;
        clonedcon.Description= con.Description;

        insert clonedcon;
        PageReference errorPage = new PageReference('/apex/ContactInsert?id='+conId);
        errorPage.setRedirect(true);
        return errorPage;


        //return new PageReference('/' +clonedcon.id+ '/e' );
        // Redirect to the new cloned record
        //return new PageReference('/'+clonedcon.Id);
        return null;
    }

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactDetailController">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" title="Contact detail" tabStyle="Contact" id="myId">

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Edit}" value="Edit" reRender="myId" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Delete}" value="Delete" reRender="myId" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!cloneButton}" value="Clone"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageblockSection >
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
         <apex:outputpanel >
         <apex:outputfield value="{!contact.Salutation}" />
         &nbsp;
         <apex:outputfield value="{!contact.FirstName}" />
         </apex:outputpanel>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.homephone}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.mobilephone}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Accountid}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.otherphone}"/> 
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.title}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.fax}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Department}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Email}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Birthdate}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.AssistantName}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Reportstoid}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Assistantphone}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.leadsource}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.OtherStreet}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.othercity}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.otherstate}"/> 
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.otherpostalcode}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingCountry}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.othercountry}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Languages__c}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Level__c}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Description}"/> 

</apex:pageblocksection>

</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

<apex:relatedList list="Cases"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Sachin.. Can I ask why you are not using `apex:detail` here..For contact detail page?

Comment: I want to use <apex:outputfield> this is my requirement and tell me how to display chatter on the top of the detail page

Comment: Sachin.. if you need same functionality as standard page `(including chatter and clone button)` then no need to do that much coding.. Salesforce already build some component for us... so what you need to do just create a page with `<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.Id}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>`  and ovverride your detail page with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create contact detail page using controller?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104747/how-to-create-contact-detail-page-using-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not aware of `<apex:detail>`

This is the component salesforce build for us...we just need to use in VF page..

Like you said in comment your need Account detail page with Chatter feed then use below code and override Account detail page with this VF page

For chatter feed you need to use `showChatter="true"`

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.Id}" relatedList="true" title="true" showChatter="true"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Above page display like below image.. Check url I am using VF page

[image]