# How to create contact detail page using controller?

Tags: community, controller, controller-extension, standardcontroller

How to create contact detail page using controller?

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactDetailController">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" title="Contact detail" tabStyle="Contact" id="myId">

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Edit}" value="Edit" reRender="myId" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Delete}" value="Delete" reRender="myId" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!cloneButton}" value="Clone"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageblockSection >
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
         <apex:outputpanel >
         <apex:outputfield value="{!contact.Salutation}" />
         &nbsp;
         <apex:outputfield value="{!contact.FirstName}" />
         </apex:outputpanel>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.homephone}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.mobilephone}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Accountid}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.otherphone}"/> 
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.title}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.fax}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Department}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Email}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Birthdate}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.AssistantName}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Reportstoid}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Assistantphone}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.leadsource}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.OtherStreet}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.othercity}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.otherstate}"/> 
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.otherpostalcode}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingCountry}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.othercountry}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Languages__c}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Level__c}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Description}"/> 

</apex:pageblocksection>

</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

<apex:relatedList list="Cases"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard controller to create detail page

For this example to render properly, you must associate the Visualforce page 
    with a valid account record in the URL.

For example, if 001D000000IRt53 is the account ID, the resulting URL should be:

https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IRt53

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.id}" relatedList="true" title="true"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Here is the reference document for [apex:details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm)

Comment: Himanshu subject should be `subject="{!account.Id}"` ? not subject="{!account.ownerId}"

Comment: actually it can be either {!account.Id} or {!account.OwnerId}. you can test in your org. ;)

Comment: Nop.. `{!account.OwnerId}` will display the Account owner i.e user detail page will display..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. yah I knew that I used this thing n number of times. I overlooked the statement. my account name and user name was same and I just looked the title when you pointed out previously. ;)